# How to merge the elements of an array of Text/TextFlow [JavaFX]

Tags: java, javafx, frontend

Which is the best practice to merge the elements of an array compose by several Text Object or TextFlow Object?

Comment: So you have an array of `Text` object and you want to get the concatenated string? Do I understand it well?

Comment: I want to get the concatenated Text or TextFlow, not the string. The problem is I have several Text objects with different style (That's why I need the concatenated Text or TextFlow). @DVarga

Comment: So you have several `Text` objects styled one-by-one and want to get them together keeping the styling. Right?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how many they are. It depends from the original String. That's why I can't use directly TextFlow tf=new TextFlow (param1, param2, etc.).

Comment: Assuming that `textArray` is a `Text[]`: `textFlow.getChildren().addAll(textArray);` works without any additional work.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't imagine it was so simple, it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi do you mean iterating over the text objects and joining them together, if so you could try this:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author dean2191
 */
public class JavaFXApplication8 extends Application {

    Text text1 = new Text("Big italic red text");
    Text text2 = new Text("Big italic red text2");

    Text[] anArray = {text1, text2};

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Text keepStyle=null;
        int i=0;
        for (Text s : anArray) {
            if(i==0)
            keepStyle=s;
            else
            keepStyle.setText(keepStyle.getText()+" "+s.getText());
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(keepStyle.getText());

        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

    }
```

If this isnt what you mean feel free to comment and i can try and help :)

Comment: I don't need the concatenated String, but the concatenated Text object. If I use this way I will loose the different styles that every Text has.

Comment: Ok do you wish to keep the style of one particular element or join all the styles together?